# Questions Related to Sequences + Sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be the $n$th sequence 1, 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 5    ,  5 , 5, . . . . . . .  constructed by including the integer $k$ exactly $k$ time. Show that $a_n$ $=$ $\lfloor \frac12 + (2n+\frac14)^.5   \rfloor$

Let $\lvert r\rvert < 1$ be a real number. Evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^\infty ir^i. $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

$$\begin{align}n&=1,\ \ 2,\ \ 3,\ \ 4,\ \ 5,\ \ 6,\ \ 7,\ \ 8,\ \ 9,\  10,\  11,\ 12,...\\
m=a_n&=1,\ \ 2, \ \ 2, \ \ 3,\ \ 3,\ \ 3,\ \ 4,\ \ 4,\ \ 4,\ \ \  4, \ \ \ 5,\ \ \ 5,... \\
&\quad  *\quad\ \ \ *\qquad\ \ \ \  *\qquad \quad \quad  \ \ * \end{align}$$

At positions marked * which occur just before $m$ steps up, 
$$\begin{align}
n&=\lbrace 1, \ 3, \ 6, 10, 15, ...\rbrace\\
m&=\lbrace 1,\ 2,\  3,  \ \ 4, \ \ 5, ... \rbrace\\
\Rightarrow n&=\sum_{i=1}^m i = \frac {m(m+1)}2\\
m^2+m-2n&=0 \\
m=a_n&=\frac{\sqrt{1+8n}-1}2\end{align}$$

As $m$ steps up $1$ each time, for all values of $n$, $m=a_n$ can be given as

$$\begin{align}
m=a_n&=\Biggl\lceil{\frac{\sqrt{1+8n}-1}2} \Biggr\rceil \\
&=\Biggl\lceil \sqrt{2n+\frac14}-\frac 12 \Biggr\rceil\\
&=\Biggl\lfloor \frac12+\sqrt{2n+\frac14} \Biggr\rfloor\\
&=\Biggl\lfloor \frac12+\left(2n+\frac14\right)^{0.5} \Biggr\rfloor\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

- $\displaystyle \sum_{i} i\cdot r^{i} = \sum_{i}\left\{ \frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{i+1}\right) -r^{i}\right\}= \frac{d}{dr} \sum_{i}r^{i+1} -\sum_{i} r^{i}$